# Title and favicon Form from webBrowser?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am creating a browser from visual studio 2010 in c # and I do not know how to give the title to the form based on the navigation, it is my first application

I'm sorry for my bad English. I'm a italian guy inexperienced.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this-

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        this.Text = webBrowser1.Document.Title;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    this.Title = doc.Title;
}
```

Comment: i have copied and pasted your text to project but this error
http://i54.tinypic.com/2mciruw.png

Comment: Remove that Navigation from your argument